# how to fix infinite loop error in log4j and logback

Tags: log4j

I need help resolving this issue:

When i run my program to call one of the methods from a library, i get following error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/6edffc576ce104ec769d954618764f39f0f0f10d/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.2/f81d1cb16fc384523de17ba46370d863bc2f691/logback-classic-1.2.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:58)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
```

Comment: found the problem. i was missing to add logback.xml file in my resources.

Comment: Make more concise and straight to point